# Microsoft access form view

Tags: ms-access-2010, ms-access-2016

I am creating a Microsoft access application, and I designed a login form, where the user inputs username and password. I want the form view of the form to be showing above the access window, as a pop-up... how do I achieve that?

Comment: google for opening popup windows in ms-access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Popup property for the form to Yes.  You probably also want to set the Modal property to Yes, which will disable the application window until the form is closed or hidden.

Comment: thank you for this.... that's what I was looking for